# .Net. Guid null when send put request

Tags: .net, rest, guid

When i send put request - The controller gets the value 0000-000... in OrderGuid
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code and data as images. Please post the actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the getter/setter fields of the model. One of the fields had the wrong identifier